# Libpng Library - Indexed-images reading out of range indexes

Tags: c, libpng

I've been dabbling with Libpng library to create PNG-based software. As I explore the library, it seems that when I read in certain paletted images, then check the 2D arrays that I produce to see if any indexes are out of range -- many actually are. And I can't seem to figure out why.

I've tried chatgpt, but it has not been particularly helpful.

Although, it did generate this debug code for me to use as a tester. I will supply the code and the file below. But first, here is the generated reading/writing code. The **output_pixel_values** function is what reads to me the value of each palette entry.

```
void read_and_write_png(const char* input_filename, const char* output_filename) {
    FILE* input_file = fopen(input_filename, "rb");
    if(!input_file) {
        printf("Can't open file %s for reading\n", input_filename);
        return;
    }

    // Initialize the reading structures.
    png_structp read_ptr = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    png_infop read_info_ptr = png_create_info_struct(read_ptr);
    png_init_io(read_ptr, input_file);
    png_read_info(read_ptr, read_info_ptr);

    png_uint_32 height = png_get_image_height(read_ptr, read_info_ptr);
    png_bytepp row_pointers = (png_bytepp)malloc(sizeof(png_bytep) * height);

    for (png_uint_32 i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        row_pointers[i] = (png_bytep)malloc(png_get_rowbytes(read_ptr, read_info_ptr));
    }

    png_read_image(read_ptr, row_pointers);

    // Now that we've read the image, let's write it to another file.
    FILE* output_file = fopen(output_filename, "wb");
    if(!output_file) {
        printf("Can't open file %s for writing\n", output_filename);
        return;
    }

    // Initialize the writing structures.
    png_structp write_ptr = png_create_write_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    png_infop write_info_ptr = png_create_info_struct(write_ptr);

    // Set up the output.
    png_init_io(write_ptr, output_file);

    // Copy the image data from the read structures to the write structures.
    png_set_IHDR(write_ptr, write_info_ptr, png_get_image_width(read_ptr, read_info_ptr),
                 png_get_image_height(read_ptr, read_info_ptr), png_get_bit_depth(read_ptr, read_info_ptr),
                 png_get_color_type(read_ptr, read_info_ptr), png_get_interlace_type(read_ptr, read_info_ptr),
                 png_get_compression_type(read_ptr, read_info_ptr), png_get_filter_type(read_ptr, read_info_ptr));

    png_colorp palette;
    int num_palette;

    if (png_get_PLTE(read_ptr, read_info_ptr, &palette, &num_palette)) {
        png_set_PLTE(write_ptr, write_info_ptr, palette, num_palette);
    }

    png_bytep trans_alpha = NULL;
    int num_trans = 0;
    png_color_16p trans_color = NULL;

    if (png_get_tRNS(read_ptr, read_info_ptr, &trans_alpha, &num_trans, &trans_color)) {
        png_set_tRNS(write_ptr, write_info_ptr, trans_alpha, num_trans, trans_color);
    }

    printf("Reading image now. . \n");
    sleep(5);
    output_pixel_values(read_ptr, read_info_ptr, row_pointers);
    printf("Done!!");
    
    // Set up the data in the write structure.
    png_set_rows(write_ptr, write_info_ptr, row_pointers);

    // Finally, write the image to the file.
    png_write_png(write_ptr, write_info_ptr, PNG_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY, NULL);

    // Clean up.
    fclose(input_file);
    fclose(output_file);

    png_destroy_read_struct(&read_ptr, &read_info_ptr, NULL);
    png_destroy_write_struct(&write_ptr, &write_info_ptr);

    // Free the memory associated with row_pointers
    for (png_uint_32 i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        free(row_pointers[i]);
    }
    free(row_pointers);
}
```

```
void output_pixel_values(png_structp png_ptr, png_infop info_ptr, png_bytep *row_pointers) {
    int width = png_get_image_width(png_ptr, info_ptr);
    int height = png_get_image_height(png_ptr, info_ptr);
    int color_type = png_get_color_type(png_ptr, info_ptr);
    int bit_depth = png_get_bit_depth(png_ptr, info_ptr);
    png_colorp palette = NULL;
    int num_palette = 0;
    if (color_type == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_PALETTE) {
        png_get_PLTE(png_ptr, info_ptr, &palette, &num_palette);
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        png_bytep row = row_pointers[y];
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            if (color_type == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB) {
                png_bytep px = &(row[x * 3]);
                printf("Pixel at (%d, %d): R=%d, G=%d, B=%d\n", x, y, px[0], px[1], px[2]);
            } else if (color_type == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGBA) {
                png_bytep px = &(row[x * 4]);
                printf("Pixel at (%d, %d): R=%d, G=%d, B=%d, A=%d\n", x, y, px[0], px[1], px[2], px[3]);
            } else if (color_type == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY) {
                int num_bytes = bit_depth == 8 ? 1 : 2;
                png_bytep px = &(row[x * num_bytes]);
                int gray_value = num_bytes == 1 ? px[0] : (px[0] << 8) + px[1];
                printf("Pixel at (%d, %d): Gray=%d\n", x, y, gray_value);
            } else if (color_type == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_PALETTE) {
                int index = row[x];
                if (index < num_palette) {
                    png_color palette_color = palette[index];
                    printf("Pixel at (%d, %d): Palette Index=%d, R=%d, G=%d, B=%d\n", x, y, index, palette_color.red, palette_color.green, palette_color.blue);

                } else {
                    printf("Index = %d\n", index);
                    printf("Pixel at (%d, %d): Palette index out of range\n", x, y);
                    row[x] = 0;
                    

                }
            }

            else {
                printf("Index = %d", row[x]);
                printf("Pixel at (%d, %d): Color type not supported\n", x, y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting NOT to receive the following:

*Index = 96
Pixel at (319, 96): Palette index out of range*

Please let me know if you all can see anything immediately wrong. Here is a link to the image I've used a tester.

https://imgur.com/a/FKSNAih

Comment: What is the value of `num_palette`?

Comment: It equals the length of the palette array for a particular image. In this case, the image I'm using has a num_palette of 10.

That means in the row_pointers that is generated, no value should be greater than 10. But you'll random values like 21, 87, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've tried chatgpt, but it has not been particularly helpful.
>
> Although, it did generate this debug code for me to use as a tester.

The artificial intelligence wasn't intelligent enough to account for other than 8-bit/pixel paletted data. You could change `int index = row[x];` to

```
            int index, ppb = 8/bit_depth;    // pixels per byte
            switch (bit_depth)
            {
            default: printf("bit depth %d not implemented\n", bit_depth); exit(1);
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 4:
            case 8: index = row[x/ppb]>>8-(x%ppb+1)*bit_depth&255>>8-bit_depth;
            }
```

or use [`png_set_packing()`](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-1.2.5-manual.html#section-3.7).

Comment: Hah, thanks for that! This has given me insight on a much larger issue with my code. I think you may have solved this particular issue. I'll get back to you.

Comment: Yep, this looks like it solves my issue. It also helps me realize mistakes I've made with other parts of my code.